# In RecyclerView, keep element expanded / selected in config changes

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-configchanges

I'm developing an Android app.
I have a RecyclerView, and I can expand my items (several at the same time).
The problem ocurrs when the orientation changes. I have a ViewModel, so the data is loaded again. But the items expanded are lost.

What is the best way to keep items expanded after a change of orientation?

android:configChanges="orientation" in Manifest isn't an option

Comment: If the items expanded are lost you lost the state somehow . Add adapter and View model code with question .

Answer (score 0):

I would save the expanded/collapsed state to the ViewModel and then apply the saved states when a configuration change occurs.